# Center Website in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, centering

I've read several posts on this subject and I've tried many of them but I cannot get my website to be centered in IE - specifically IE 8 (my current browser).  It does work in FF, Safari and Chrome.  [www.hscassociates.net](http://www.hscassociates.net) is the site.

In my css I'm doing this:

```
div#section {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #b31b1b;
  border-top:none;
}
```

Also, I have a background image I need in my #section div, but it will not show when I place it in my css file in the div#section block.  In order to get it to show, I put it inside the  in my includes file where I am displaying the #section div tag:

```
<div id="section" style="background-image:url('graphics/section-bg.gif'); 
                         background-repeat:repeat-y;">
```

One post I read said the html doctype needed to be using strict.  I've never read that before.  Any truth to that?  I'm using transitional.

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone. Take this. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hscassociates.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1):

Your `DOCTYPE` should be the first tag on your page. Because it is not IE is rendering your page in what is known as [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). The DOCTYPE itself doesn't need to be strict but what will happen is with a correct DOCTYPE the page will be rendered in strict mode instead.

**What is quirks mode?**

Because certain old browsers didn't meet W3C standards developers had to write non-standards compliant code to ensure their pages looked correct in these browsers. As browsers came closer to the standard the problem was that pages developed in the old style would no longer render correctly. So they implemented two modes of rendering, **quirks** and **strict**.

If the website supplies a DOCTYPE as the first argument this tells the browser that the page is written in standards compliant code and what specification to render against. So the browser can use strict mode to render the page.

However if the page omits a DOCTYPE then the browser does not know what specification to render against and therefore assumes the page is non-standards compliant (Which it automatically is for omitting the DOCTYPE) and renders it in quirks mode which can have unexpected results.

**Here's what you need to do:**

Change

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
```

Comment: How do I post code to a reply with a code snippet?  This "add comment" box won't take a return/new-line.   I hit the enter key and it posts my comment.  Sigh!

Comment: @JohnCowan Your website has tons of errors. One of the main ones being `<div id="section">` has no closing tag (may cause your problem)... go here http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hscassociates.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0, fix those errors and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` triggers quirks mode.

If you want to use HTML 4 Transitional then use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

If you are not bound to HTML 4 then use `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Your page displays fine with both.